# mpf_class setting precision, assigning, freeing and converting to string

Tags: c++, string, gmp

I'm having trouble following the documentation for GMP https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats there is no examples for what I want to do. It might be more than 1 question but I don't think that they are too long for having 4 individual questions asking for each answer.

1. How can I initialize a `mpf_class` with 20 decimal places of precision
2. How can I set a value to my `mpf_class` with any precision I want, eg: `mpf_class myNum = 3.1415926535897932000000000000000000000000123456789`
3. How can I make an `std::string` hold the value of my `mpf_class` with the precision (lets say my `std::string` holds exactly the number above (3.14...)
4. From my understanding with `gmp` (without the mpf_class) you need to manage the memory, ie, `mpf_clear()` is there any memory managment that I need to do with `mpf_class`? If so what are they?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of pretty nice examples in the GMP distribution itself, just look at the `tests/` directory. Or in here, just search for the tag `gmp` and refine.

1. Note [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150035/calculating-bits-required-to-store-decimal-number/40746823) to represent a decimal number in binary you need roughly speaking about `log(10)/log(2) = 3.322...` times binary digits than that of decimal digits. So, you use

   Function: void mpf_class::set_prec (mp_bitcnt_t prec)

after delcaring the class instance, with precision set to 20 * 3.322, and GMP will alloc enough space for that to fit, and a little bit more, to fill in the integer number of limbs.

2. To initialize a `mpf_t` variable to arbitrary precision you can't use numeric constants in C/C++, like your example, because those numeric literals are interpreted as `float` or `double` according to your platform, and might not have the desired precision. In C++, use instead the string overload assignment, like so: `mpf_class myNum; myNum = "3.1415926535897932000000000000000000000000123456789"`. C++ overload will call the `mpf_init_set_str` behind the scenes for you.
3. As above, but note that conversion from decimal to binary float has subtleties, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Binary-to-decimal_conversion_with_minimal_number_of_digits) and [here](https://ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf). So, you have to understand what accuracy your decimal numbers have, and perhaps have a tolerance compare if required to do so (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611257/approximation-using-gmp-mpf-class/70615995#70615995)).
4. With `mpf_class` you need to just declare the object instance and then delete it if you need to clear memory. With `mpf_t` you need to call `mpf_init()`, for example, and after using it, call `mpf_clear()` if needed. Note that all of those will be cleared from memory at program exit, as per operating system standards. You only need to worry about memory allocation, with `malloc` and `free`, and the alike, if you use the `mpn_` raw "difficult to use" [functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions).