# How can I calculate required bits for an unsigned value?

Tags: java, logarithm

For a given unsigned `int` value, I tried following method for the number of bits for storing given value.

```java
    // Returns the number of required bits for (storing) specified unsigned value.
    static int size(final int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value(" + value + ") is negative");
        }
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(value) / Math.log10(2));
    }
```

And here comes what I got.

```
size for 1310394095: 31              (RANDOM)
size for 1: 0                        (1; Not Good; should be 1)
size_NotNegative_Zero() is @Disabled (0; ERROR; Expecting actual: -2147483648 ...)
size for 2147483647: 31              (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

The `31` for `Integer.MAX_VALUE` seems OK.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746823/5811874

Answer (score 0):

Although I flagged my own question as a duplicate, I'm posting what I found.

The problem is that the input is not just positive but also including zero and that's why the way of simply dividing *log<sub>whatever</sub>v* with *log<sub>whatever</sub>2* won't work cuz *log<sub>whatever</sub>0* is not defined.

Here comes what I concluded with https://stackoverflow.com/a/680040/330457.

```java
    static int size(final int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value(" + value + ") is negative");
        }
        if (value == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
    }
```

```
size for 909663241: 30  (RANDOM)
size for 1: 1           (ONE)
size for 0: 1           (ZERO)
size for 2147483647: 31 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```