# How do I solve the 'classic' knapsack algorithm recursively?

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem

This is my task

> The Knapsack Problem is a classic in computer science. In its simplest
>   form it involves trying to fit items of different weights into a
>   knapsack so that the knapsack ends up with a specified total weight.
>   You don't need to fit in all the items. For example, suppose you want
>   your knapsack to weigh exactly 20 pounds, and you have five items,
>   with weights of 11, 8, 7, 6, and 5 pounds. For small numbers of items,
>   humans are pretty good at solving this problem by inspection. So you
>   can probably figure out that only the 8, 7, and 5 combination of items
>   adds up to 20.

I really don't know where to begin writing this algorithm. I understand recursion when applied to factorials and triangle numbers. However I'm lost right now.

Comment: how else would you solve the NP problem than by recursion?

Comment: Dynamic Programming for example. No recursion needed. You may always try to change NP-complete program into pseudo-polynomial, knapsack is one of those problems.

Comment: I like to listen experienced-**wise** people before going deeper into a subject. To be skillful on DP, one needs to be skillful on _Recursion, Memoized approach and
Bottom-up(Tabulation) approach_. That's why the guy highly likely ponders its recursive way like me.

Comment: So, @Benjamin's saying is genuinely minute right. No recursion is needed, yet recursion formula is inevitable sine qua non for DP.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What did you try?

The idea, given the problem you stated (which specifies we must use recursion) is simple: for each item that you can take, see if it's better to take it or not.  So there are only two possible path:

1. you take the item
2. you don't take it

When you take the item, you remove it from your list and you decrease the capacity by the weight of the item.

When you don't take the item, you remove if from you list but you do not decrease the capacity.

Sometimes it helps to print what the recursive calls may look like.  In this case, it could look like this:

```
Calling 11 8 7 6 5  with cap: 20
 +Calling 8 7 6 5  with cap: 20
 |  Calling 7 6 5  with cap: 20
 |    Calling 6 5  with cap: 20
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 20
 |      Result: 5
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 14
 |      Result: 5
 |    Result: 11
 |    Calling 6 5  with cap: 13
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 13
 |      Result: 5
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 7
 |      Result: 5
 |    Result: 11
 |  Result: 18
 |  Calling 7 6 5  with cap: 12
 |    Calling 6 5  with cap: 12
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 12
 |      Result: 5
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 6
 |      Result: 5
 |    Result: 11
 |    Calling 6 5  with cap: 5
 |      Calling 5  with cap: 5
 |      Result: 5
 |    Result: 5
 |  Result: 12
 +Result: 20
  Calling 8 7 6 5  with cap: 9
    Calling 7 6 5  with cap: 9
      Calling 6 5  with cap: 9
        Calling 5  with cap: 9
        Result: 5
        Calling 5  with cap: 3
        Result: 0
      Result: 6
      Calling 6 5  with cap: 2
        Calling 5  with cap: 2
        Result: 0
      Result: 0
    Result: 7
    Calling 7 6 5  with cap: 1
      Calling 6 5  with cap: 1
        Calling 5  with cap: 1
        Result: 0
      Result: 0
    Result: 0
  Result: 8
Result: 20
```

I did on purpose show the call to [8 7 6 5] with a capacity of 20, which gives a result of 20 (8 + 7 + 5).

Note that [8 7 6 5] is called twice: once with a capacity of 20 (because we didn't take 11) and once with a capacity of 9 (because with did take 11).

So the path to the solution:

11 not taken, calling [8 7 6 5] with a capacity of 20

8 taken, calling [7 6 5] with a capacity of 12 (20 - 8)

7 taken, calling [6 5] with a capacity of 5  (12 - 7)

6 not taken, calling [5] with a capacity of 5

5 taken, we're at zero.

The actual method in Java can fit in very few lines of code.

Since this is obviously homework, I'll just help you with a skeleton:

```
private int ukp( final int[] ar, final int cap ) {
    if ( ar.length == 1 ) {
        return ar[0] <= cap ? ar[0] : 0;
    } else {
        final int[] nar = new int[ar.length-1];
        System.arraycopy(ar, 1, nar, 0, nar.length);
        fint int item = ar[0];
        if ( item < cap ) {
            final int left = ...  // fill me: we're not taking the item
            final int took = ...  // fill me: we're taking the item
            return Math.max(took,left);
        } else {
            return ... // fill me: we're not taking the item
        }
    }
}
```

I did copy the array to a new array, which is less efficient (but anyway recursion is not the way to go here if you seek performance), but more "functional".

Answer (score 17):

I had to do this for my homework so I tested all of the above codes (except for the Python one), but none of them work for every corner case.

This is my code, it works for every corner case.

```
static int[] values = new int[] {894, 260, 392, 281, 27};
static int[] weights = new int[] {8, 6, 4, 0, 21};
static int W = 30;

private static int knapsack(int i, int W) {
    if (i < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (weights[i] > W) {
        return knapsack(i-1, W);
    } else {
        return Math.max(knapsack(i-1, W), knapsack(i-1, W - weights[i]) + values[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(knapsack(values.length - 1, W));}
```

It is not optimized, the recursion will kill you, but you can use simple memoization to fix that. Why is my code short, correct and simple to understand? I just checked out the mathematical definition of the 0-1 Knapsack problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming

Comment: Is there a way of keeping track of the unique items you used in this recursion? I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours now with no success.

Comment: @crashprophet, [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: I think it is `if (i <0 || W ==0) return 0`

Answer (score 10):

The problem is basically modified version of classic knapsack problem for simplicity (there **are no values/benefits** corresponding to weights) (for actual: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem, [0/1 Knapsack - A few clarification on Wiki's pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073768/0-1-knapsack-a-few-clarification-on-wikis-pseudocode/24906286#24906286), [How to understand the knapsack problem is NP-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907545/how-to-understand-the-knapsack-problem-is-np-complete), [Why is the knapsack problem pseudo-polynomial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538581/why-is-the-knapsack-problem-pseudo-polynomial?lq=1), http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/).

Here are five versions of solving this in c#:

**version1**: Using dynamic programming (tabulated - by eagerly finding solutions for all sum problems to get to final one) - O(n * W)

**version 2**: Using DP but memoization version (lazy - just finding solutions for whatever is needed)

**version 3** Using recursion to demonstrate overlapped sub problems and optimal sub structure

**version 4** Recursive (brute force) - basically accepted answer

**version 5** Using stack of #4 (demonstrating removing tail recursion)

**version1**: Using dynamic programming (tabulated - by eagerly finding solutions for all sum problems to get to final one) - O(n * W)

```
public bool KnapsackSimplified_DP_Tabulated_Eager(int[] weights, int W)
        {
            this.Validate(weights, W);
            bool[][] DP_Memoization_Cache = new bool[weights.Length + 1][];
            for (int i = 0; i <= weights.Length; i++)
            {
                DP_Memoization_Cache[i] = new bool[W + 1];
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= weights.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w <= W; w++)
                {
                    /// f(i, w) determines if weight 'w' can be accumulated using given 'i' number of weights
                    /// f(i, w) = False if i <= 0
                    ///           OR True if weights[i-1] == w
                    ///           OR f(i-1, w) if weights[i-1] > w
                    ///           OR f(i-1, w) || f(i-1, w-weights[i-1])
                    if(weights[i-1] == w)
                    {
                        DP_Memoization_Cache[i][w] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DP_Memoization_Cache[i][w] = DP_Memoization_Cache[i - 1][w];
                        if(!DP_Memoization_Cache[i][w])
                        {
                            if (w > weights[i - 1])
                            {
                                DP_Memoization_Cache[i][w] = DP_Memoization_Cache[i - 1][w - weights[i - 1]];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return DP_Memoization_Cache[weights.Length][W];
        }
```

**version 2**: Using DP but memorization version (lazy - just finding solutions for whatever is needed)

```
/// <summary>
        /// f(i, w) determines if weight 'w' can be accumulated using given 'i' number of weights
        /// f(i, w) = False if i < 0
        ///           OR True if weights[i] == w
        ///           OR f(i-1, w) if weights[i] > w
        ///           OR f(i-1, w) || f(i-1, w-weights[i])
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rowIndexOfCache">
        /// Note, its index of row in the cache
        /// index of given weifhts is indexOfCahce -1 (as it starts from 0)
        /// </param>
        bool KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(int[] weights, int w, int i_rowIndexOfCache, bool?[][] DP_Memoization_Cache)
        {
            if(i_rowIndexOfCache < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(DP_Memoization_Cache[i_rowIndexOfCache][w].HasValue)
            {
                return DP_Memoization_Cache[i_rowIndexOfCache][w].Value;
            }
            int i_weights_index = i_rowIndexOfCache - 1;
            if (weights[i_weights_index] == w)
            {
                //we can just use current weight, so no need to call other recursive methods
                //just return true
                DP_Memoization_Cache[i_rowIndexOfCache][w] = true;
                return true;
            }
            //see if W, can be achieved without using weights[i]
            bool flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights,
                w, i_rowIndexOfCache - 1);
            DP_Memoization_Cache[i_rowIndexOfCache][w] = flag;
            if (flag)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (w > weights[i_weights_index])
            {
                //see if W-weight[i] can be achieved with rest of the weights
                flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights,
                    w - weights[i_weights_index], i_rowIndexOfCache - 1);
                DP_Memoization_Cache[i_rowIndexOfCache][w] = flag;
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

**where**

```
public bool KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(int[] weights, int W)
        {
            this.Validate(weights, W);
            //note 'row' index represents the number of weights been used
            //note 'colum' index represents the weight that can be achived using given 
            //number of weights 'row'
            bool?[][] DP_Memoization_Cache = new bool?[weights.Length+1][];
            for(int i = 0; i<=weights.Length; i++)
            {
                DP_Memoization_Cache[i] = new bool?[W + 1];
                for(int w=0; w<=W; w++)
                {
                    if(i != 0)
                    {
                        DP_Memoization_Cache[i][w] = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //can't get to weight 'w' using none of the given weights
                        DP_Memoization_Cache[0][w] = false;
                    }
                }
                DP_Memoization_Cache[i][0] = false;
            }
            bool f = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(
                weights, w: W, i_rowIndexOfCache: weights.Length, DP_Memoization_Cache: DP_Memoization_Cache);
            Assert.IsTrue(f == DP_Memoization_Cache[weights.Length][W]);
            return f;
        }
```

**version 3** Identifying overlapped sub problems and optimal sub structure

```
/// <summary>
        /// f(i, w) = False if i < 0
        ///           OR True if weights[i] == w
        ///           OR f(i-1, w) if weights[i] > w
        ///           OR f(i-1, w) || f(i-1, w-weights[i])
        /// </summary>
        public bool KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(int[] weights, int W, int i)
        {
            if(i<0)
            {
                //no more weights to traverse
                return false;
            }
            if(weights[i] == W)
            {
                //we can just use current weight, so no need to call other recursive methods
                //just return true
                return true;
            }
            //see if W, can be achieved without using weights[i]
            bool flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights,
                W, i - 1);
            if(flag)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(W > weights[i])
            {
                //see if W-weight[i] can be achieved with rest of the weights
                return this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, W - weights[i], i - 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**where**

```
public bool KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(int[] weights, int W)
        {
            this.Validate(weights, W);
            bool f = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, W,
                i: weights.Length - 1);
            return f;
        }
```

**version 4** Brute force

```
private bool KnapsackSimplifiedProblemRecursive(int[] weights, int sum, int currentSum, int index, List<int> itemsInTheKnapsack)
        {
            if (currentSum == sum)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (currentSum > sum)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (index >= weights.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            itemsInTheKnapsack.Add(weights[index]);
            bool flag = KnapsackSimplifiedProblemRecursive(weights, sum, currentSum: currentSum + weights[index],
                index: index + 1, itemsInTheKnapsack: itemsInTheKnapsack);
            if (!flag)
            {
                itemsInTheKnapsack.Remove(weights[index]);
                flag = KnapsackSimplifiedProblemRecursive(weights, sum, currentSum, index + 1, itemsInTheKnapsack);
            }
            return flag;
        }
        public bool KnapsackRecursive(int[] weights, int sum, out List<int> knapsack)
        {
            if(sum <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sum should be +ve non zero integer");
            }
            knapsack = new List<int>();
            bool fits = KnapsackSimplifiedProblemRecursive(weights, sum, currentSum: 0, index: 0, 
                itemsInTheKnapsack: knapsack);
            return fits;
        }
```

**version 5: Iterative version using stack (note - same complexity - using stack - removing tail recursion)**

```
public bool KnapsackIterativeUsingStack(int[] weights, int sum, out List<int> knapsack)
        {
            sum.Throw("sum", s => s <= 0);
            weights.ThrowIfNull("weights");
            weights.Throw("weights", w => (w.Length == 0)
                                  || w.Any(wi => wi < 0));
            var knapsackIndices = new List<int>();
            knapsack = new List<int>();
            Stack<KnapsackStackNode> stack = new Stack<KnapsackStackNode>();
            stack.Push(new KnapsackStackNode() { sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack = 0, nextItemIndex = 1 });
            stack.Push(new KnapsackStackNode() { sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack = weights[0], nextItemIndex = 1, includesItemAtCurrentIndex = true });
            knapsackIndices.Add(0);

            while(stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var top = stack.Peek();
                if(top.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack == sum)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach(var index in knapsackIndices)
                    {
                        var w = weights[index];
                        knapsack.Add(w);
                        count += w;
                    }
                    Debug.Assert(count == sum);
                    return true;
                }
                //basically either of the below three cases, we dont need to traverse/explore adjuscent
                // nodes further
                if((top.nextItemIndex == weights.Length) //we reached end, no need to traverse
                    || (top.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack > sum) // last added node should not be there
                    || (top.alreadyExploredAdjuscentItems)) //already visted
                {
                    if (top.includesItemAtCurrentIndex)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(knapsackIndices.Contains(top.nextItemIndex - 1));
                        knapsackIndices.Remove(top.nextItemIndex - 1);
                    }
                    stack.Pop();
                    continue;
                }

                var node1 = new KnapsackStackNode();
                node1.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack = top.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack;
                node1.nextItemIndex = top.nextItemIndex + 1;
                stack.Push(node1);

                var node2 = new KnapsackStackNode();
                knapsackIndices.Add(top.nextItemIndex);
                node2.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack = top.sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack + weights[top.nextItemIndex];
                node2.nextItemIndex = top.nextItemIndex + 1;
                node2.includesItemAtCurrentIndex = true;
                stack.Push(node2);

                top.alreadyExploredAdjuscentItems = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**where**

```
class KnapsackStackNode
        {
            public int sumOfWeightsInTheKnapsack;
            public int nextItemIndex;
            public bool alreadyExploredAdjuscentItems;
            public bool includesItemAtCurrentIndex;
        }
```

**And unit tests**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void KnapsackSimpliedProblemTests()
        {
            int[] weights = new int[] { 7, 5, 4, 4, 1 };
            List<int> bag = null;
            bool flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 10, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(4));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 3);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 3, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 7, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(7));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 1, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);

            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Tabulated_Eager(weights, 10);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Tabulated_Eager(weights, 3);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Tabulated_Eager(weights, 7);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Tabulated_Eager(weights, 1);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);

            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(weights, 10);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(weights, 3);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(weights, 7);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_DP_Memoization_Lazy(weights, 1);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);

            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, 10);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, 3);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, 7);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplified_OverlappedSubPromblems_OptimalSubstructure(weights, 1);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);


            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 10, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(4));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 3);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 3, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 7, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(7));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 1, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);

            weights = new int[] { 11, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 20, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(8));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(7));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 3);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 27, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 11, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(11));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);
            flag = this.KnapsackSimplifiedProblemIterativeUsingStack(weights, 5, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);

            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 20, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(8));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(7));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 3);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 27, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsFalse(flag);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 11, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(11));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);
            flag = this.KnapsackRecursive(weights, 5, knapsack: out bag);
            Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Contains(5));
            Assert.IsTrue(bag.Count == 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple recursive implementation (not very efficient, but easy to follow). It's in Python, OP is asking for a Java implementation, but porting it to Java shouldn't be too difficult, it's like looking at pseudo-code.

The main function declares three parameters: V is an array of values, W is an array of weights and C the capacity of the knapsack.

```
def knapsack(V, W, C):
    return knapsack_aux(V, W, len(V)-1, C)

def knapsack_aux(V, W, i, aW):
    if i == -1 or aW == 0:
        return 0
    elif W[i] > aW:
        return knapsack_aux(V, W, i-1, aW)
    else:
        return max(knapsack_aux(V, W, i-1, aW),
                   V[i] + knapsack_aux(V, W, i-1, aW-W[i]))
```

The algorithm maximizes the value of the items added to the knapsack, returning the maximum value attainable with the given weights

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see it.

Comment: @Óscar López: you have answered the "real" knapsack but not his problem, which seems simpler since that there's apparently no value/weight distinction in the OP's problem.

Comment: What do you mean by values? You have a W for weight next to it so it can't be weight.

Comment: @cokedude "V is an array of values". What gets maximized it's the values from this array

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, I run your code as "knapsack([2, 3], [1, 2], 2)" and received 3 as an output. Are you sure it is working correctly? Or am I missing something? I expected 4, because we can take first element with weight 1 and value 2 twice.

Comment: @Hasek you can’t take the same element twice ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Knapsack {
    public int[] arr = {11,8,7,6,5};
    public int[] retArr = new int[5];
    int i = 0;
    public boolean problem(int sum, int pick) {
        if(pick == arr.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if(arr[pick] < sum) {   
            boolean r = problem(sum - arr[pick], pick+1);           
            if(!r) {
                return problem(sum, pick+1);
            } else {
                retArr[i++] = arr[pick];
                return true;
            }                   
        } else if (arr[pick] > sum) {
            return problem(sum, pick+1);
        } else {
            retArr[i++] = arr[pick];
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Knapsack rk = new Knapsack`enter code here`();
        if(rk.problem(20, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Success " );
            for(int i=0; i < rk.retArr.length; i++)
                System.out.println(rk.retArr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another dynamic programming implementation in Java. 
I always feel top-down DP using memoization is much easier to understand than bottom up DP.

Complete, self-explanatory, runnable code, using data from [this example from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKnapsack.svg):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Knapsack {

    private static final List<Item> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, Bag> CACHE = new HashMap<>();
    private static final boolean FINITE_ITEMS = true; //whether an item can be added more than once

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ITEMS.add(new Item(4, 12, "GREEN"));
        ITEMS.add(new Item(2, 2, "CYAN"));
        ITEMS.add(new Item(2, 1, "GREY"));
        ITEMS.add(new Item(1, 1, "ORANGE"));
        ITEMS.add(new Item(10, 4, "YELLOW"));
        Bag best = bestBagForCapa(15);
        System.out.println(best.toString());
    }

    public static Bag bestBagForCapa(int capa) {
        if (CACHE.containsKey(capa)) return CACHE.get(capa);
        if (capa < 0) return null;
        if (capa == 0) return new Bag(0, 0);

        int currentWeight = -1;
        int currentValue = -1;
        String newItem = null;
        List<String> previousItems = null;
        for (Item p : ITEMS) {
            Bag previous = bestBagForCapa(capa - p.weight);
            if (previous == null) continue;

            int weightSoFar = previous.weight;
            int valueSoFar = previous.value;
            int nextBestValue = 0;
            Item candidateItem = null;
            for (Item candidate : ITEMS) {
                if (FINITE_ITEMS && previous.alreadyHas(candidate)) continue;
                if (weightSoFar + candidate.weight <= capa && nextBestValue < valueSoFar + candidate.value) {
                    candidateItem = candidate;
                    nextBestValue = valueSoFar + candidate.value;
                }
            }

            if (candidateItem != null && nextBestValue > currentValue) {
                currentValue = nextBestValue;
                currentWeight = weightSoFar + candidateItem.weight;
                newItem = candidateItem.name;
                previousItems = previous.contents;
            }
        }

        if (currentWeight <= 0 || currentValue <= 0) throw new RuntimeException("cannot be 0 here");
        Bag bestBag = new Bag(currentWeight, currentValue);
        bestBag.add(previousItems);
        bestBag.add(Collections.singletonList(newItem));
        CACHE.put(capa, bestBag);
        return bestBag;
    }

}

class Item {

    int value;
    int weight;
    String name;

    Item(int value, int weight, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

class Bag {

    List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
    int weight;
    int value;

    boolean alreadyHas(Item item) {
        return contents.contains(item.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "weight " + weight + " , value " + value + "\n" + contents.toString(); 
    }

    void add(List<String> name) {
        contents.addAll(name);
    }

    Bag(int weight, int value) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def knpsack(weight , value , k , index=0 , currweight=0):
    if(index>=len(weight)):
        return 0
take = 0
dontake = 0
if(currweight+weight[index] <= k):
    take = value[index]  + 
         knpsack(weight,value,k,index+1,currweight+weight[index])
dontake = knpsack(weight,value,k,index+1,currweight)
return max(take,dontake)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one

```
    static int[] values = new int[] {1,3,5,6};
static int[] weights = new int[] {2,3,4,5};
static int W = 8;

private static int calculate(int i, int W, int cur) {
    // this second check on wts is required so that if there is no space if we try this weight, dont proceed
    if (i == values.length || W - weights[i] <= 0) return cur;
    return Math.max(calculate(i+1, W, cur), calculate(i+1, W - weights[i], cur + values[i]));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculate(0, W, 0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Java solution

```
static int knapsack(int[] values, int[] weights, int W, int[] tab, int i) {
    if(i>=values.length) return 0;
    if(tab[W] != 0) 
        return tab[W];      

    int value1 = knapsack(values, weights, W, tab, i+1);        
    int value2 = 0;
    if(W >= weights[i]) value2 = knapsack(values, weights, W-weights[i], tab, i+1) + values[i];

    return tab[W] = (value1>value2) ? value1 : value2;
}
```

Test it by using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = new int[] {894, 260, 392, 281, 27};
    int[] weights = new int[] {8, 6, 4, 0, 21};
    int W = 30;
    int[] tab = new int[W+1];
    System.out.println(knapsack(values, weights, W, tab, 0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple recursive solution in Java but you should avoid using recursion if possible.

```
public class Knapsack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{11, 8, 7, 6, 5};
        find(arr,20);
    }

    public static boolean find( int[] arr,int total){
        return find(arr,0,total);
    }

    private static boolean find( int[] arr,int start,  int total){
        if (start == arr.length){
            return false;
        }
        int curr = arr[start];
        if (curr == total){
            System.out.println(curr);
            return true;
        }else if (curr > total || !find(arr,start+1,total-curr)){
            return find(arr,start+1,total);
        }
        System.out.println(curr);
        return true;
    }
}
```