# I'm trying to solve the "knapsack" problem using Java and recursion

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

This is for a school assignment and the professor stipulates that recursion must be used, and it must take a single line input in a gui box where the first number is the max capacity (weight) the knapsack can hold and the rest are item weights. This doesn't include the value, just weight.

It is partially working, as it is following the tree properly and indicating how many solutions there are (via debugging output) but I am having trouble being able to record the valid solutions. It seems to work fine on returns from recursive calls when at the ends of the branches due to storing and removing the items from the sack[] array.

As far as I can tell from stepping through the code a million times is that it fails when returning somewhere else. This leaves stray items sitting in the sack that shouldn't be there. Hopefully someone will be able to see where I am doing something dumb and help me go in the correct direction. I have deleted and rewritten the code in this so many times that I am about to throw my computer out of a window. lol

I know this is a lot, but I couldn't think of how to properly describe what I am having trouble with other than just posting the entire program. Thanks in advance for any help anyone might be able to provide.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

// Main Program
class n00868494 {

   static int itemCount = 0; // total number of items 
   static int pos = 0; // position indicator in the "sack" array
   static int sack[] = new int[25]; // sack to hold items on right branches

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String sinput[] = new String[25]; // temp string array to hold parameters before     converting to integers
   int items[] = new int[25]; // array to hold the items
   int capacity = 0; // knapsack capacity
   String s = null; // temp string to hold user input

   while (true) { // infinite loop

      // Use a JOptionPane dialog to get the user's input
      s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame("Input Params"), "Please enter total weight, followed a list of item weights)","Run Parameters",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

      if ((s == null) || (s.equals(""))) { // user pressed X, cancel or left it blank.
         System.exit(0);  // exit cleanly
      }

      sinput = s.split(" "); // split the parameters on the whitespace

      for (int i = 0; i < sinput.length; i++) { // iterate through the array and copy the elements to the correct variables
         if (i == 0) {
            capacity = Integer.parseInt(sinput[i], 10); // knapsack weight in the first position
         } else {
            items[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(sinput[i], 10); // the rest are item weights
         }
      }
     items = Arrays.copyOfRange(items, 0, sinput.length - 1); // truncate the items array to remove empty elements at the end

      knapSack(capacity, items); // call the knapsack method that will in turn call the recursive function
   }   
      }

   public static void knapSack(int capacity, int[] items) {

      itemCount = items.length; // keep track of original number of items

      recknapSack(capacity, items, 0); // start recursive calls
   }


   /*
      recursive knapsack method: called repeatedly to find the correct combinations of items such that their weights
  total to the max capacity that the knapsack can hold

      capacity: knapsack capacity
      items: array of items (weights)
      branch: flag indicating whether the call is a left branch (item not included) or right branch (item included)
         0 - initial call, non recursive
         1 - left branch, weight not included
         2 - right branch, weight included
   */
   public static void recknapSack(int capacity, int[] items, int branch) {

      System.out.print("\nCap: " + capacity + " Items: " + Arrays.toString(items)); // recursive call tracking debugging

      if (capacity == 0){ // debugging - for breaking at certain points in the tree
         assert Boolean.TRUE; // set breakpoint on this line
      }


      // base cases - ends of the branches
      if (capacity == 0){ // sack is exactly full, item weights = total weight
            System.out.print("\t  -> good tree"); // debugging
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("Results"), "The valid combinations are: ");
            Arrays.fill(sack, 0); // clear the sack, this was a successful branch, will start again for another solution
            return;
      } else if (capacity < 0) { // bag overloaded
            System.out.print("\t  -> overload tree"); // debugging
            if (branch == 2) // if this is an "included" branch
               sack[--pos] = 0; // remove the last item placed in the sack
        return;
           } else if (items.length == 0){ // out of items and/or capacity not reached
        System.out.print("\t  -> empty src tree"); // debugging
        if (branch == 2)
           sack[--pos] = 0;
        return;
   } else {

     int firstItem; // this the first item, it will either be discarded (not included) or placed in the sack array (included)
     firstItem = items[0];

     items = Arrays.copyOfRange(items, 1, items.length); // for either recursive branch: remove the first item from the list

     recknapSack(capacity, items, 1); // call recursive function, left branch, where item is discarded and not placed in sack

     // prepare for right branch, where item is placed in sack
     capacity -= firstItem; // subtract the left most item weight from from capacity
     sack[pos++] = firstItem; // place the item in the sack
     recknapSack(capacity, items, 2); // recursive right branch call, item is placed in sack, weight subtracted from capacity

  }

  return;
   }
}
```

Comment: see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774769/how-do-i-solve-the-classic-knapsack-algorithm-recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in your code is that when it gets to the last else statement, it is not removing the initial value that was put in.  I made a small change to your code that may get you the results you are looking for.  First, I had the recursive function return an int, which would be the capacity:

```
 public static int recknapSack(int capacity, int[] items, int branch) {
```

I changed every return statement to:

```
 return capacity;
```

Then inside of the else statement, I added the following:

```
 else {

             int firstItem; // this the first item, it will either be discarded (not included) or placed in the sack array (included)
             firstItem = items[0];

             items = Arrays.copyOfRange(items, 1, items.length); // for either recursive branch: remove the first item from the list

             recknapSack(capacity, items, 1); // call recursive function, left branch, where item is discarded and not placed in sack

             // prepare for right branch, where item is placed in sack
             capacity -= firstItem; // subtract the left most item weight from from capacity
             int temp = pos;
             sack[pos++] = firstItem; // place the item in the sack
             System.out.println("First item " + firstItem);
             int ret = recknapSack(capacity, items, 2); // recursive right branch call, item is placed in sack, weight subtracted from capacity
             if(ret != 0)
             {
                  System.out.println("Removing " + sack[temp] + " at position " + (temp));
                 sack[temp] = 0;
                 pos = temp;
             }


      }
```

This will keep the sack the same unless the capacity were not 0.  You are still removing everything from the sack if you find it to be 0, so if you need to store that information, I would suggest that in the situation where it does work, you store the sack into an ArrayList of arrays that will contain all of the perfect solutions.  If you need solutions in a situation where there is no perfect solution, you can also store every solution in there and have it ordered by the lowest capacity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the help. That worked almost 100%. For my first two test cases: capacity = 20; items = 11 8 7 6 5 (1 solution), and capacity = 20; items = 11 9 8 7 6 5 (3 solutions) it works perfectly. However, when I tried something like capacity = 50; items = 11 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 it had the solutions, but also some sets that didn't sum up to 50. I couldn't figure out why, but I have to move on to other assignments in other classes so when I added a display routine, I just check each set to make sure it sums to the capacity before displaying it. It's a terrible hack, I know.