# maximizing number of quantities given cost of each number of quantity and total money with us

Tags: arrays, algorithm, backtracking, knapsack-problem

given two 1D arrays . first array A containing the number of candles as integers , the second B array contains cost of the corresponding number of candles i.e
Ai number of candles cost Bi and so on.

we are also given an integer `K(total money)`

we need to print the maximum number of candles we can purchase whose cost does not increase `K(total money)`.
all the data types are `non negative` integers.

```
Eg : k=10 A:(2 3 4 5 6 )  B:(4 5 2 10 6)  answer is 10(4+6)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: we have two arrays A[] (number of candles) and B[] ( cost of corresponding number of candles). an integer K ( max money with us) . we have to give the maximum number of candles one can buy.

Comment: That is the task you are working on. What problem are you having with it, or are you asking us to just give you the code for it?

Comment: no this is not the task . This is a sub problem that i encountered while working and now i'm stuck with it. my task is a bit complicated so to avoid complications i converted it a simple problem for asking..

Comment: i guess i have to use backtracking but i'm unable to apply on it

Comment: tell me if i got this wrong: each candle costs a different amount and you are looking for the highest number of candles with a sum you have...??
or is the first array the array of number of candles??

Comment: first array is of number of candles. and second array  of the cost of corresponding number of candles. the total cost of all number of candles must be <=K(total money).

Comment: This is the Knapsack problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774769/how-do-i-solve-the-classic-knapsack-algorithm-recursively

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Amount of candles in your cast is value of item, but cost is weight.