# Limitations of Dynamic Programming algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

After exploring this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860882/knapsack-with-continuous-non-distinct-constraint) I came to realize that dynamic programming algorithms can't be used to solve [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or similar problems with a **non-integer constraint**. Am I right about my realization? Are there any other limitations of Dynamic Programming algorithms?

Comment: I imagine that in addition to here, the folks at the Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) would have a lot of insight into this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you could say the number of possible scores (solution quality) needs to be finite and low enough to fit in memory. Non-integer in general means non-discrete and that leads to infinite possible solution scores.

If there are only N possible solution scores you know that you will at most need to find N of them to also get the best one, not the whole exponential amount of ways to get to them. That's the idea behind dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose another limitation is that it isn't known if dynamic programming is the best available technique, given that its performance isn't known to match information theoretic lower bounds.

Here is [an example problem from David Eppstein](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/open/algo.html#dynprog):

> Given a sorted list of n real numbers, find the smallest interval
>   containing exactly k elements, for all values of k between 1 and n.
>   There is a simple dynamic programming algorithm that solves this
>   problem in quadratic time, but the best known lower bound is only
>   linear. Either describe a faster algorithm, or prove a bigger lower
>   bound in some reasonable model of computation. ("Dynamic programming"
>   is not a reasonable model of comptuation!!)